# How to query DynamoDB with for multiple ids eg: student_id in [1,2,3] #rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table in DynamoDB.

```
student_id, name, age, address  partition_key: student_id, table_name: students
```

lets say student ids are 1,2,3 etc...
I wanted to query students based on Ids.
eg sql select * from students where id in (1,2,3)

How to do the same in DynamoDB

Please help me with the query params.
I tried

```rb
params = {
:table_name=>"students",
:key_condition_expression=>"student_id IN :student_id",
:expression_attribute_values=>{":student_id"=> [1,2,3]}
}
```

Comment: I am getting ```Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type``` for the above code if i make `=` instead of IN. I guess 'IN' is not supported

Comment: It might be just an issue that it's confused with the fact that the hash key is called the same as the table key.

I have never used DynamoDB, but have you tried writing something like this?


```ruby
params = {
:table_name=>"students",
:key_condition_expression=>"student_id IN :student_ids",
:expression_attribute_values=>{":student_ids"=> [1,2,3]}
}

```

Comment: `IN` is not supported in key_condition_expression

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not allow you to apply conditionals around the partition key (e.g. PK in [1,2,3]), you need to specify it explicitly.  However, you *can* perform various condition operations around sort keys (<,>, begins_with, etc).

Comment: That doesn't help me

Comment: It should help you from continuing down the wrong path of trying to figure out the right parameters to send the query operation.  The problem isnt with the query operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify the primary key, which I'm assuming is your student_id and you want students with id 1, 2, and 3, then you can use the client [batch_get_item()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html#batch_get_item-instance_method).

Comment: One more scenario. Assume there is a project_id in student table. What if I wanted to query student which work on specific projects? `select * from students where project_id in (1,2,4)` ?

Comment: There are data modeling docs out there for DynamoDB which are worth reading, especially if your background is SQL, not NoSQL. In the project query, I’m assuming that a given student can work on multiple projects so you might want a second ProjectStudents table keyed on project_id + student_id, and then make 3 queries (not gets) on project_id values of 1, 2, and 3. That’s also largely how you’d model this in SQL, but both ID fields would have foreign key constraints. You want to avoid table scans, in general, because they read every item in the table.